# How to get the Id of an entity submitted with symfony2 form

Tags: symfony

My problem is very simple but complicated for me, I have a `symfony2` form CategoryType:

```
class CategoryType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'entity', array('class' => 'Mpk\CmsBundle\Entity\Category',
                                      'placeholder' => '',
                                      'property' => 'name',))

        ->add('save', 'submit')
    ;
}
```

and I want get the id of selected entity after submition in my controller how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id_selected = $form->getData()->getName()->getId();
```

Comment: Thank you too much you save my time... since two weeks I've search for that !

Answer (score 1):

Please note, you might not be able to get the id of the entity when it is newly created as it is not generated before the entity is persisted in the database. If you must get it you'll have to persist the entity first. If this isn't possible and you need to uniquely identify the entity before persisting, some options might be to maybe generate the id manually, or maybe make the entity name unique (and use it instead), or maybe create a separate column/parameter and make that unique. Of course, all of these options will require you to confirm your item is actually unique.